# Functions Invoking other Functions exercise I'm stumped on

Tags: javascript, function, invoke, replit

First-time poster here and have run into a speed bump in my pre-work for a 6-month full-stack boot camp I'm enrolled in for November.

I'm working on some exercises on `repl.it` and this one is on javascript functions. You're told to write 3 functions called mealMaker, slice, and cook.

You're given an empty array and are told to fill it with objects like so:

```
const arrayOfFoodObjects = [
  {
   "food": "beef",
   "type": "meat"
  },
  {
   "food": "zucchini",
   "type": "vegetable"
  },
  {
   "food": "bacon",
   "type": "meat"
  },
  {
   "food": "okra",
   "type": "vegetable"
  }
];
```

They want you to have the cook function take all the objects that have "type": "meat" and return a string that says "Cooked ("food": value)" (e.g. "Cooked beef") and similarly with the slice function for "type": "vegetable" they want "("food": value) slices" (e.g. "Okra slices").

Then the mealMaker function takes what those functions spit out and creates an array as such: ["Cooked beef", "Okra slices" ...].

Where I'm stuck is I wrote a .filter() function that just returns a filtered array of those objects which I soon realized wouldn't serve its purpose. I guess I'm trying to figure out how to write a function so I can filter the meat and vegetables separately and then have them spit out the required string.

What's confusing me is how to target the "food" value and plug it into a certain string after filtering with the "type" value.

This is the rest of the code I have written so far which may or may not help.

```
var redMeat = arrayOfFoodObjects.filter(function(cook) {
      return cook.type == "meat";
});


var veggies = arrayOfFoodObjects.filter(function(slice) {
      return slice.type == "vegetable";
});

console.log(veggies, redMeat)
```

With the console just looking like:

```
[ { food: 'zucchini', type: 'vegetable' },
  { food: 'okra', type: 'vegetable' } ] [ { food: 'beef', type: 'meat' },
  { food: 'bacon', type: 'meat' } ]
```

I'm probably not tackling this the right way as I've spent a good amount of time trying different things I had found on Google and applying them as best I could but this was the closest I managed to get. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

PS I'm not super familiar with this format of a function as I came up with this through some searches on Google. If someone wouldn't mind explaining how this may differ from the function format I'm used to seeing, that'd be awesome. I'm not sure about which part of it is the "name" of the function. The functions I've worked with so far typically look like:

```
function nameOfFunction(value(s)) {
     *action*;
}
```

Comment: Create a function that takes a filterVegetables and a filterMeat function as a parameter. 
Inside you can verify the type in any iterator/loop and then call the appropriate function depending on the type.
Sorry if this wasn't helpful, not sure I understood the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing what they ask.
They want a `cook` function and a `slice` function:

```
function cook(arr){
    //for each element of the array, return its mapped value (they ask a string)
    return arr.map( function(foodObject){
        return `Cooked ${foodObject.food}`
    })
}
function slice(arr){
    //do it
}
let cooks = cook(arrayOfFoodObjects)
let slices = slice(arrayOfFoodObjects)
```

then feed what the function spit out to `mealMaker` (as instructed):

```
function mealMaker(cooks, slices){
    return cooks.map( function(cook, idxCook){
        let slice = slices[idxCook];
        //guess what to do with cook and slice
    })
}
mealMaker(cooks, slices)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something alone these lines is requested:

```
const cook = product => "cooked " + product.food;
const slice = product => product.food + " slices";

const mealMaker = (products) => {
  const meatProducts = products.filter(product => product.type === "meat");
  const veggieProducts = products.filter(product => product.type === "vegetable");
  return [
    ...cook(meatProducts),
    ...slice(veggieProducts)
  ];
}

mealMaker(arrayOfFoodObjects);
```

Notice the fat arrow syntax for writing functions. How it is different compared to regular functions, is explained [here on Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome holdenprkr!

I think you are on the right track! For now, we have a way to get an **array** of veggies and another one for meats:

```
var redMeat = arrayOfFoodObjects.filter(function(cook) {
    return cook.type == "meat";
});


var veggies = arrayOfFoodObjects.filter(function(slice) {
    return slice.type == "vegetable";
});
```

So far so good, now we want a **cook function** that takes our `readMeat` array, and converts it to a **array of strings**. So, something in the lines of:

```
function cook(readMeatsArray) {
    // convert readMeatsArray to cookedMeatsArray
    // [{'food': 'beef', 'type': 'meat'}, ...]
    // to
    // ['Cooked beef', ...]
}
```

And then a **slice function** for the veggies:

```
function slice(veggiesArray) {
    // convert veggiesArray to slicedVeggiesArray
    // [{'food': 'okra', 'type': 'vegetable'}, ...]
    // to
    // ['Okra slices', ...]
}
```

So, if we combine this in an **mealMaker function** we now have:

```
function mealMaker() {
    // First we get our arrays
    var redMeat = arrayOfFoodObjects.filter(function(cook) {
         return cook.type == "meat";
    });

    var veggies = arrayOfFoodObjects.filter(function(slice) {
        return slice.type == "vegetable";
    });

    // Then we convert our object arrays to string arrays
    var cookedMeats = cook(redMeat);
    var slicedVeggies = slice(veggies);

    // Now we combine the resulting arrays and return it
    var mealArray = cookedMeats.concat(slicedVeggies);

    return mealArray;
}
```

This would be one approach, hope it helps.

PD: I left the functions **cook** and **slice** empty on purpose, you can get some inspiration from user753642's answer ;)